# How can I web map service published by Dojo in Flex app

Tags: web-mapping, arcgis-flex-api, dojo

We want to include a base map layer in hosted Flex app. We requested web map service from the vendor and I got a file (.htm) from client with some dojo code. I can understand the code but I am not sure how can I include this in my flex app configuration:

```
    // info used to create web tile layers
    var mapurl  = "http://bnvnbvnn/${0}/${2}/${1}.png"
    var lyr = new esri.layers.WebTileLayer(mapurl);
    // clear out the side bar
    //dojo.byId("leftPane").innerHTML = "";
    // create and add the layers
    //var layerDiv = dojo.create("div");
    map.addLayer(lyr);

  }
```

If I will replace variables on URL, I can see images but how will I use this for Flex configuration- where it comes like this:

```
 <layer url="http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer" 
visible="true" type="tiled" label="ArcGIS Streets"/>
```

I have never worked with Dojo toolkit, so I have no idea (or may be there is some communication gap)

Thanks

Comment: Your best bet is to start with the ESRI Resource Center. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/flex-api/

Comment: To me, that URL has the markings of an OpenStreetMap (OSM) tile/format deployment, and if so, I believe you can consume it without a struggle in the ESRI Flex-viewer using their [`OpenStreetMapLayer`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/apiref/index.html?com/esri/ags/layers/OpenStreetMapLayer.html&com/esri/ags/layers/class-list.htmlf) class. I posted an example that I suspect will nearly copy..paste right into your app.

Answer (score 2):

@user8732, the url in the vendor-provided dojo stuff implies an OpenStreetMap-themed tile distribution, which leaves me thinking you can implement it using ESRI Flex-viewer's [built-in `OpenStreetMapLayer` class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/apiref/index.html?com/esri/ags/layers/OpenStreetMapLayer.html&com/esri/ags/layers/class-list.html).

ESRI provides [an example complete with source](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html#/OpenStreetMap/01nq0000000m000000), and If I adapt that example based on what's explained in the `OpenStreetMapLayer` API, I'd get the code you find below.

```
<esri:Map logoVisible="false"
          openHandCursorVisible="false"
          wrapAround180="true">
    <esri:OpenStreetMapLayer>
        <esri:tileServers>
            <fx:String>http://bnvnbvnn/</fx:String>
            <fx:String>http://bnvnbvnn/</fx:String>
            <fx:String>http://bnvnbvnn/</fx:String>
        </esri:tileServers>
    </esri:OpenStreetMapLayer>
</esri:Map>
```

The repetition you find in the server addresses, above, is necessary to resolve a JavaScript limitation. I'm not aware if this issue affects Flex, and the code I proposed assumes it does *not* affect Flex (hence three of the exact same server paths). However, if you find this *is* an issue in Flex and you want to resolve it the JavaScript way, you can create 3 DNS addresses that all point to the same host; i.e. http://a.bnvnbvnn/, http://b.bnvnbvnn, and http://c.bnvnbvnn.

BostonGIS [explains this](http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=using_custom_osm_tiles#231) in point #3 as follows (realize they are talking aboug JavaScript, specifically, but on a high-level it relates to your Flex implementation, too):

> *NOTE: We have an array of 3 tile urls. For our case, this is pretty useless, but for load balancing purposes and to also get rid of
>   javascripts limitations of calling a server x amount of times in any
>   period, you may want to setup more than one tile server or mask your
>   single tile server with multiple dns names (to fool javscript).*